# How to click an image with Selenium with only an SRC

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<td colspan="2" align="center">
        <img src="web/L001/images/IMAGENAME.jpg" width="213" height="46" border="0" onclick="javascript: MessageDisplay()" ></td>
```

This is the element I'm trying to click. 
My attempted code:

```
WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("web/L001/images/Phishing_12.jpg"));
temp.click();
```

I even tried with the full address, but any ides would be appreciated.

I use this to log on to various websites but this particular one throws up a web-page before that I have to click on that element before I can continue.
-Thx

Comment: You are not Using correct xpath of the image. that why u r facing an error message

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This xpath should find it

```
WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='web/L001/images/IMAGENAME.jpg']"));
```

or use contains like so

```
WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'web/L001/images/IMAGENAME.jpg')]"));
```

But i think the problem would be is that you are not `wait`ing for the element.

Answer (score 8):

Generally CSS selectors are favored over xpaths. That's why I would recommend:

```
WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src='web/L001/images/IMAGENAME.jpg']"));
```

Comment: You can use a wild card as well so that `By.cssSelector("a[src='web/L001/images/IMAGENAME.jpg']")` can be expressed as `By.cssSelector("a[src*='MAGENAME.jpg']")`

Comment: Pretty sure this should be `By.css("img[src='web/L001/images/IMAGENAME.jpg']")`